# how to delete a row of user from table using Angular2?

Tags: angular

This is the `deleteUser` function of user service which call the backend server

```
 deleteUser(id:number)
 {
     return this.http.delete(`${this.Url}/${id}`)
 }
```

and this is the `userComponent` which display the list of users on a grid. 
I want to delete user by clicking on 'supprimer'

```
@Component({
    template: <ul *ngFor=" let x of users">
            <li>{{x.id}}</li>
            <li>{{x.firstName}}</li>
            <li>{{x.lastname}}</li>
            <li>{{x.username}}</li>
            <li>{{x.password}}</li>
            <li><a (click)="deleteItem(x.id)">supprimer</a></li>
        </ul>
})

export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    private users: User[];

    constructor(private userService: UserService ,private router:Router) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        his.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => {this.users = data })
    }

    deleteItem(id:number) {
        this.userService.deleteUser(id).subscribe(   );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove an item from "users" object, declare an index of the current object.

```
<ul *ngFor=" let x of users; let i = index;">
   <li><a (click)="deleteItem(x.id, i)">supprimer</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can splice from your collection using this index

```
  deleteItem(id:number, index:number) {
    this.userService.deleteUser(id).subscribe(response =>{
         this.users.splice(index, 1);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user Service:  
DeleteUser(_id:any){
    return this.httpClient.delete<any>(`${environment.APIURL}/users/${_id}`,this.options)
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res
    }))
  }

user Component.ts:
 DeleteUser(user: any) {
    this._userservice.DeleteUser(user._id).subscribe(res => {}`enter code here`
```