# How to fetch the index number of the clicked row in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am fetching data from URL in JSON format and have shown it on html. See below image -

[image]

I want to click on the name and fetch the array index of the clicked row

How can I do this?

Below is my html code in case you need it:

```
<ion-row *ngFor = "let list of list"> 
          <ion-col>{{list.ID}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.PRODUCTSERVICE}}</ion-col> 
          <ion-col>{{list.NAME}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.UNIT}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.CATEGORY}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.HSN}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.POSTINGHEAD}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.RATE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.TYPE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.SACCODE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col><ion-icon ios="ios-close-circle" md="md-close-circle"></ion-icon></ion-col> 
       </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use index with ngFor

```
<ion-row ngFor = "let list of list; let i = index;> 
<ion-col (click)="generate(i);">{{list.ID}}</ion-col>
```

and corresponding ts would be,

```
generate(index) {
    console.log('index', index);
}
```

Comment: hard to see any difference in answer just elaborating it

Comment: Its just that i added the ts method and on how to pass the index. both are same though

Comment: and what to code so that clicked item gets deleted ?

Comment: @user2828442 you should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236594/how-to-delete-a-row-of-user-from-table-using-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<ion-row *ngFor = "let list of list; let i = index; " (click)="getIndex(i)"></ion-row>
```

**component.ts**

```
getIndex(index) {
    console.log('index', index);
}
```

Comment: hard to see any difference in answer just elaborating it

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
```

Now you can pass this index to a `click` method of every ion-row.

Comment: please shed some light on why the dv ?